# IPC::Shareable store hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash, ipc, fork

I am writing a script in perl where I use forking and I need to share variables among the separate processes. Currently I am using [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/~bsugars/IPC-Shareable-0.60/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm), which has been working great. However, it does not seem to work for a hash of hashes. For example:

```
$todo->{$next_todo_key}{'urls_hash'} = \%temp;

or 

$todo->{$next_todo_key}{'url_idlist'} = $url_idlist;
```

Will give me the error `IPC::Shareable::SharedMem: shmget: File exists
 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/IPC/Shareable.pm line 566
Could not create shared memory segment: File exists`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or a similar module that will allow me to store a hash of hashes? Thanks!

Comment: [IPC::Shareable](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Shareable) on MetaCPAN

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a solution there. I typically refuse to use any CPAN module that hasn't had a release since 2001. I was just linking over to MetaCPAN, since it's the new, better search.cpan.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend giving [DBM::Deep](https://metacpan.org/module/DBM%3a%3aDeep) a try. You've probably gone beyond what a shared memory tool is going to give you if you need hashes of hashes.

You can store the DBM::Deep database in a RAM-disk if you really want it to be transient, or just use a temp file you can clean up at the end of your script run.